# What is a single-word adjective to define someone in power by virtue of contacts?

Tags: adjectives

If not a single-word adjective, then anything as concise that may define the following traits an individual possess:

- They possess power, in terms that they can make other people do things at their whim.
  It doesn't matter what the source of their power is: could be influence, ability to convince or confuse, threat, by virtue of age/experience/respect earned.
  For instance, each example from different category: "Godfather" from that movie, politicians, subject matter experts, teacher, police.
- They have the right contacts, each for a specific job. - Essencially a "Network of people at their disposal" (e.g politicians and businessmen).
  They know somebody on whom they possess power (above point), and that individual is either authority, or empowered enough to pull in a favour (or their instruction).

Note: It'll be great to know an adjective that need not necessarily imply a criminal intent. A neutral adjective would be preferred.

An adjective I can think of closely resembling this would be "stature", however it requires context to be clear.

Comment: Do you want an adjective or a noun? "Stature" is a noun.

Comment: The power to make people do something on a whim is actually very unusual.

Answer (score 2):

To borrow from your question, you might consider [**influential**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/influential).

> : exerting or possessing influence

Similarly, I'd suggest [**well-connected**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-connected):

> : having important and powerful friends

Definitions from Merriam-Webster.

Answer (score 0):

> [authoritarian](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/authoritarian) (Noun):
>
> someone who demands that people obey completely and
> refuses to allow them freedom to act as they wish.

It can be adjective as well.

> authoritarian (adjective)
>
> demanding that people obey completely and refusing to 
> allow them freedom to act as
> they wish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this does not convey that they have a "network of people" at their disposal. Any other suggestion that may bring in this essence?

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the powerful contacts in this scenario they may be 'placemen.' [oxforddictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/placeman)

> **Placeman**  *British derogatory*
>      A person appointed to a position, especially in government service, for personal profit and as a reward for political support.

It need not be government; but it usually needs a big organisation.